# Apply a graphic style

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

How do I apply a graphic style (called 'line1') to a `PathItem` using ExtendScript in Adobe illustrator?

Answer (score 3):

```
// Get the style named "line1"
var style = app.activeDocument.graphicStyles.getByName("line1");
// Apply the style to your path item
style.applyTo(pathItem);
```

Comment: Also, `app.activeDocument.graphicStyles` appears to be an array, the docs suggest using `app.activeDocument.graphicStyles[0]` to get the first one, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the [Illustrator Scripting Guide](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/scripting/cs6/Illustrator-Scripting-Guide.pdf) has to say about applying graphic styles (page 17):

> Your script can apply a graphic style to artwork using the `graphic style` object. To apply a graphic style, use the `graphic styles` property of the `document` object to access the `apply to` method of the `graphic style` object.

Note that the object names given are for AppleScript. It looks like in ExtendScript uses slightly different names: the `graphic style` object is, instead, the `ArtStyle` object. Use its `.applyTo()` method.