# Change Illustrator TextFrameItem aspect

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

Using ExtendScript for Illustrator, I need to create programmatically AI documents from scratch, with stroked texts.

I created texts with the following code:

```
textFrame.contents = 'foo'
textFrame.textRange.characterAttributes.textFont = textFont
textFrame.textRange.fillColor = black
textFrame.textRange.stroked = true
textFrame.textRange.strokeColor = white
textFrame.textRange.strokeWeight = 0.75
```

but I am getting cropped glyphs because stroke is drawed above the text fill.

[image]

So I would like to be able to add fill and stroke "aspects" like in Illustrator user interface, then put stroke aspect bellow fill aspect. I didn't find how to manage aspect with ExtendScript Illustrator API. Does anyone know how to do that?

Creating text outline is not an option because I want to keep texts editable. Neigher creating 2 texts one on top of the other for the same reason.

Comment: It looks like Illustrator's JSX API doesn't have such option. I'd try to make a graphic style and save it in a separate ai-file. Then you can open the ai-file copy the style (or the sample of a styled text) into the new document and apply the style upon the your text https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040419/apply-a-graphic-style

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try : create manually a Graphic Style in a base document then apply it to my new texts.